# Rails Query Issue

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have photos which have_many comments.

I want to select whatever photos have recent comments and display those photos in a kind of "timeline" where the most recently commented photo is at the top and other photos fall below.

I tried this, and it worked on SQLite:

```
@photos = Photo.select('DISTINCT photos.*').joins(:comments).order('comments.created_at DESC')
```

However testing on PostgreSQL raises this error:

```
PGError: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
\n: SELECT DISTINCT photos.* FROM \&quot;photos\&quot; INNER JOIN \&quot;comments\&quot; ON \...
```

So, the problem is, I'm selecting Photos but ordering by recency of comments... and Postgre doesn't like that.

Can anyone suggest either:

A: How I can fix this query...

or

B: A different way to retrieve photos by the recency of their comments?

The important reason I'm doing it this way instead of through the comments model is I want to show each photo once with any recent comments beside it, not show each comment by itself with the same photos appearing multiple times.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the :touch parameter of of the belongs_to association:

> :touch
>
> If true, the associated object will be
>   touched (the updated_at/on attributes
>   set to now) when this record is either
>   saved or destroyed. If you specify a
>   symbol, that attribute will be updated
>   with the current time instead of the
>   updated_at/on attribute.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

In your Comment model, therefore, you would have:

```
belongs_to :photo, :touch => :comments_updated_at
```

Now, in order to create a time line of photos with recently updated comments all you need to do is:

```
Photo.order('comments_updated_at DESC').all
```

Just be sure to add the "comments_updated_at" datetime field to your Photo model.

Make sense?

Comment: sorry, I don't get it... what does this fix for me?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer to be more thorough. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, ok, I get it. Only problem is this returns all photos for some reason... I'll keep tweaking it but if you have any suggestions let me know.

Comment: Ok, fixed the issue above just by including .joins(:comments). Thanks, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the future readers of this question, the real answer to your *SQL* issue in SQlite vs Postgresql is that in the SQL "standard", every selected column needs to be in the GROUP BY or be an aggregate function.

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php (or whatever SQL ref you want to take a look at)

Your SQLite query used `SELECT *` instead of specific columns. That would have blown up with a similar error on most databases like Postgresql (MySQL, Maria, probably MSSQL Server). It's definitely invalid SQL grammar for a lot of good reasons.

Under the hood, I have no clue what SQlite does -- maybe it expands the * into fields and adds them to the `GROUP BY` under the hood? But its not a good SQL statement which is which it threw the error.